# regex is right - yet match returns nil - why?

Tags: ruby, regex

Good sirs.

I seem to have a decent regex to capture the url I want...

[image]

So how am I using it wrong?

```
2.0.0-p451 :237 > resbody
 => "{"provider_url": "http://www.popsci.com", ...
2.0.0-p451 :240 > resbody.match(/"thumbnail_url":"([^"]*)"/)
 => nil
2.0.0-p451 :241 > resbody.scan(/"thumbnail_url":"([^"]*)"/)
 => []
2.0.0-p451 :242 > resbody[/"thumbnail_url":"([^"]*)"/,1]
 => nil
```

Comment: Obvious question that needs to be asked: why not just use `JSON.parse` and then access `thumbnail_url` from the resulting hash?

Comment: 2.0.0-p451 :256 > JSON.parse(resbody)["thumbnail_url"] indeed works!

Comment: I pasted the wrong hash here. Actually there was another one that came from the API wrong and JSON.parse couldn't deal with it at all. That set me down the road of regex, and I still hope to find out how to deal with such strings correctly.

Comment: Whould be interesting to the the JSON string you had problems with...

Comment: Went back in my history and it seems this is the same hash that didn't work for me 3 hours ago! I think at the time it came to me as a string inside a string -> ""{"provider_url": "http://www.popsci.com", ..."". I'm sure it was something I did wrong in irb. But it's working right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string looks like JSON. Therefore the following should return the what you need:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(resbody)['thumbnail_url']
```

Comment: Thanks sir. It works! (and thumbnail_url is what I need - you can see it in the screenshot - not in my redacted code sample)